# Creating an AdHoc connection

Tags: wireless-access-point, adhoc

When I create a wireless AdHoc network, Ubuntu keeps switching back to my router. I can't see the network I created on my other computers either. In fact, I don't think it ever creates the network..

I've searched on Google for people having similar problems and found this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1412707

So I made sure that I uninstalled `dnsmasq` and only have `dnsmasq-basic` installed. But the problem still persists.

I need to create an adhoc network so that I can connect to my printer.